# Use Ito's Lemma to compute $d(\log S(t))$ and use this to find the closed form solution of S(t)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion

I am having issues with this practice problem. If someone could help me solve it that would be greatly appreciated!

> Let $S(t)$ be the stock price that satisfies the BSM model in SDE form
>   $$dS(t) = \mu S(t) dt + \sigma S(t) dW_t$$ 
>   where $\mu > 0$ and $\sigma > 0$ are two constants. Use Ito's Lemma to compute $d \log S(t)$ and use this result to find the closed form solution of $S(t)$.

Comment: Pure PSQ. How this managed to get 5 upvotes is a mystery.

Comment: @Did What is PSQ?  And why is this post from 2 1/2 years ago, receiving so much attention today?  The answer I posted received one up vote and 2 unexplained down votes today.

Comment: @MarkViola PSQ = Problem Statement Question (an acronym for questions with no personal input from the OP, not interested in the maths but in seeing their homework done asap, for free). "And why is this post from 2 1/2 years ago, receiving so much attention today?" Maybe the non-answer posted last month put it in a queue of some sort, but I do not know for sure (and does it matter anyway?).

Comment: Don't you just hate TLA?  LOL … As far as the question "does it matter anyway?" it only matters to satiate my curiosity.  I have posted more than 4000 answers.  From time to time an answer posted quite some time ago has received a vote.  But I have never seen a case in which an answer posted quite some time ago receive multiple votes (especially in a single day).

Comment: @MarkViola Whatever you wish to say, please use `@`.

Comment: @Did Yes, I forgot to use the "@."  Did you find the irony in my asking "Don't you just hate TLA?"

Answer (score 13):

Let $S(t)$ be governed by the SDE

$$dS(t)=\mu S(t)dt+\sigma S(t)dW_t$$

Let $f(S)=\log(S)$.

Heuristically, we can write

$$\begin{align}
d\log(S)&=\frac{\partial f(S)}{\partial t}\,(dt)+\frac{\partial f(S)}{\partial S}\,(dS)+\frac12\frac{\partial ^2f(S)}{\partial S^2}(dS)^2\\\\
&=\frac{\partial \log(S)}{\partial t}\,(dt)+\frac{\partial \log(S)}{\partial S}\,(dS)+\frac12\frac{\partial ^2\log(S)}{\partial S^2}(dS)^2\\\\
&=(0)\,dt+\frac1S\,(dS)-\frac{1}{2S^2}(dS)^2\\\\
&=\left(\mu-\frac12 \sigma^2\right)\,dt+\sigma dW_t \tag 1
\end{align}$$

Now, integrating both sides of $(1)$ yields

$$\begin{align}
\int_0^t d\log(S(t'))&=\log(S(t)/S(0)\\\\
&=\int_0^t\left(\left(\mu-\frac12 \sigma^2\right)\,dt'+\sigma dW_t'\right)\\\\
&=\left(\mu-\frac12 \sigma^2\right)t+\sigma (W(t)-W(0))\\\\
S(t)=&S(0)e^{\left(\mu-\frac12 \sigma^2\right)t+\sigma (W(t)-W(0))}
\end{align}$$

Comment: Would the down voter care to comment?

Comment: Why does this keep getting down voted 2 1/2 years after it was posted.

Comment: hi there, may I ask how would the third line of the equation evaluating $d \log (S)$ says $\frac{\partial\log(S)}{\partial t} = 0$. Why is that? it that only the movement of S is a function of t, but not the trajectory of S itself?

Comment: @BaffinChu These are partial derivatives with respect to the state variable $S$ and time $t$.

Comment: as I thought that S can be expressed in t, like S(t)..., if that is the case, then then I guess it can be chain-ruled?

Comment: @BaffinChu The function $f(S,t)$ is a function of $S$ and $t$, where $S$ is a state variable that does NOT depend on $t$.. Here, $f(S,t)=\log(S)$, which is NOT a function of $t$.  See [THIS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/It%C3%B4%27s_lemma) for both rigorous and heuristic approaches.

Comment: Thanks for clear things up :)

Comment: @BaffinChu You're welcome.  My pleasure.

Answer (score 3):

As the title of the question says, it's just a straightforward application of Ito's lemma:
Since $S$ satisfies the given SDE, $(\log)'(x)=x^{-1}$, and $(\log)''(x)=-x^{-2}$, we have
$$
\begin{split}
d(\log (S_t))&= \frac{1}{S(t)}dS_t-\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{S_t^2}\sigma^2S_t^2dt\\
&= \mu dt+\sigma dW_t-\frac{\sigma^2}{2}dt\\
&=(\mu-\frac{\sigma^2}{2})dt+\sigma dW_t
\end{split}
$$
And this is just the SDE of the Brownian with drift.