# State Price Density Integration - Related to Ito's lemma

Tags: stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, valuation-theory

I want to derive the original state price density from its dynamics by using Ito's lemma.

The dynamics of state price density $H$ is:

$$dH = -rH\,dt - \theta H\,dW(t)$$

The lecturer's solution to this is:

$$H(T) = H(0)\exp\left[(-r-0.5 \,\theta^2)T - \theta\,dW(T)\right]$$

But every time I compute it, my solution is always:

$$H(T) = H(0)\exp\left[(-r+0.5 \, \theta^2)T - θdW(T)\right]$$

The way I used to compute it is set its log function and apply Ito's lemma to the log function, which is the same as in the website [Use Ito's Lemma to compute $d(\log S(t)$ and use this to find the closed form solution of S(t)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1636956/use-itos-lemma-to-compute-d-log-st-and-use-this-to-find-the-closed-form-so)

Is the lecturer's solution wrong? Or the method I used is problematic?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: The way you describe computing it is correct, and leads to your instructor's answer, not yours. As can be seen by plugging $\mu=-r$ and $\sigma =-\theta$ into Mark's solution in the linked answer. (It's unclear to me why you're getting the other thing.)

Comment: Thank you very much Spaceisdarkgreen. I just found that I made a very stupid mistake regarding the computation process. But now I can derive the right answer :)